# How do you navigate the invisible maze in the desert?

Tags: ramble-planet

One of the earliest reachable puzzles in Ramble Planet is a maze in the desert, where the walls are invisible.

[image: Introduction to the invisible maze.]

I initially thought that the path through the maze changed depending on where you'd been or come from in the maze (so you'd have loops and stuff).  However, it's not clear to me any more if this is the case.  It's pretty confusing.

What path(s) do I need to take to grab all three of the objects?

[image: Full Maze]

Comment: can you confirm the maze swaps? just completed it, myself, and it didnt, for me.

Comment: It feels like walls open up and close based on where you've come from.  Maybe I'm just confused, I seem to have a lot more trouble than I should have for a static maze.  Will test again later.

Comment: Okay, maybe it doesn't swap.  Still would like to know the path.

Comment: Was about to comment suggesting they may have used a fake wall, if they are also using invisible walls. Realised this took me five seconds to test - and what do you know. All three parts. There you go :)

Comment: I'm going to suggest an edit to the title, as this practice is a strategy to tackle and invisible maze. Just revert back if you dont agree

Comment: @Timelord64 While yes, this could be used for any game the answer also includes game specific information, and it makes more sense to have this as a game specific title, as the OP is asking about navigating a specific maze in a specific game (and your answer addresses such.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the image you provided, I went through the maze, myself. As I encountered an invisible wall, I sprayed the section in, using paint.

I was not able to collect the last part through the maze. I went around the outside, and one of the walls collapsed, allowing me to get to it. I have marked this on the map, in green.

[image]

Comment: Ah, you're correct, it's a static maze (also not randomly generated, mine was the same as yours).  I also figured out how to get the last item in the lower right, but I'm not sure if I should spoil that here.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Simply connected maze's can be solved using the *Wall Follower* technique where you simply stick to one side of the maze:

[image: Wall Follower]

While it's more difficult since you can't see the walls, it will still work, you will just be walking into the wall a lot trying to determine if there is a wall there or not. Also an added requirement is to collect all the parts before exiting, if you reach the exit before collecting all parts simply continue on, all corridors will be traversed using this method.

However, it's not guaranteed that this solution will work as the maze may not be simply connected. Simply connected means that all the walls are connected together or to maze's outer boundary. Since the maze is invisible this condition is not known.

If the entrance and exit are both on the perimeter of the maze (as well as all the parts) then the wall follow method will still work.

Your image shows the player in the middle of the maze so I'll assume that that is where you start. The reason that it will not work in this case, is because the player could be on a section disjointed from the exit so you could constantly go around a ring.

In this situation you will need to use the *Pledge Algorithm*. This is similar to the wall follower method but is designed to pass obstacles.

To use the pledge algorithm, pick an arbitrary direction to go towards, when you encounter an obstacle follow the obstacle (similar to the wall follower) while counting the angles turned, (+1 for left, -1 for right, or vice versa). When you are facing the original direction again and the sum of the turns made is 0, leave the obstacle and continue in the original direction.

Here's a video to help understand the [pledge algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KxAMV-2tKU)